# Unity Object Collision to Counter

Tags: javascript, user-interface, counter, collision

I have an object controlled by the player that, when it hits another object that is being spawned, adds to a counter. I have the counter scripted as such:

```
static var Counter: int = 0;

function Update () {

    guiText.text = "Balloons caught: "+Counter;

    }
```

I have the player object coded with a collection script, but I'm not sure I did it correctly:

```
var collectedObjects : int = 0;

function Update(){
    if(GUIScript.Counter >= 5){
       Application.LoadLevel(0);
       GUIScript.Counter = 0;
    }
}

function OnControllerColliderHit(hit : ControllerColliderHit){
    if(hit.gameObject.tag == ("Finish")){
       GUIScript.Counter += 1;
       hit.collider.gameObject.active = false;
    }
}
```

How can I set it up so that when the player object collides with one of the objects being spawned, it adds one to the counter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The script itself is not wrong. However I don't know what it is interacting with, right now you could have misassigned components, not declared tags, not assigned tags.

If I were you I'd start with the following script, to check if all peripheral settings are as they should be:

```
static var COUNTER : int = 0;

function OnControllerColliderHit(){
     COUNTER++;
}
```